# Visual Studio 2019 New Git Experience to able to merge conflicts

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Just had to upgrade to VS 2019 v16.8.3 so that I can test out .Net 5 and it now includes the new Git experience. I made some changes to a branch and I'm now trying to merge back into my master. I get the message at the top of my VS that there are conflicts with a link for "Resolve the conflicts". When I click on that link it will open up the Git Changes pane but I'm not seeing any files that are conflict or how I would go about merging the conflicts. I did find one post where MSFT said you had to right click on the file and choose merge but I'm not seeing where the conflicting files are. Not much out there about this since it's such a recent change. Anyone have an idea on how I can find my conflicting files and how to address the conflicts?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It doesn't show what to do when there are conflicts. It just shows how to merge.

Comment: My VS has starting doing this too... How can we go back to the previous experience that actually worked?